# Labeling one bar in altair

Tags: python, label, bar-chart, altair

I'd like to label one exact bar in bar chart made up by altair, but I can't find the information about that option - only labeling the whole plot, which I'm not interested at. May be there is something like altair.condition for coloring, for example? So I can label a bar according to the condition. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example for "label one exact bar"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example, here(https://pastebin.com/Yifwwpaz) I highlight the bar, which value is equal to some variable. And I also want this value to be written, but I don't know how to label one bar (bar chart - https://pastenow.ru/JEJ2W)

Answer (score 1):

Labeling one bar is doable, there are just a few extra steps. I'll be using the built-in `airports` dataset to demonstrate.

```
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

airports = data.airports().query("country == 'USA'").dropna()

airports['label'] = False  # create new column
airports.loc[airports['state'] == 'NY', 'label'] = True  # choose state to label in the new column

airports_bar = alt.Chart(airports).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y('state:N', sort = 'x'),
    x=alt.X('count()', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
    color=alt.Color('label', legend=None),
    tooltip=['count()']
)
```

As explained in the comments in the code above, we simply create a new column which will contain the bar that we want to label. I chose to label `NY`; once we create the new column, we simply set its value of `NY` to be `True`. This will then be used in the color argument to color `NY` separately from all the other states. To label `NY` with the count value, we use `mark_text` in which we filter/query for `NY` specifically, not the whole dataframe. This allows us to only label `NY` and not the other states. The code and plot is shown below:

```
airports_bar + alt.Chart(airports.query("state == 'NY'")).mark_text(dx=10).encode(
    y=alt.Y('state:N'),
    x=alt.X('count()', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
    text='count()')
```

[image]

Note that, although not shown in this demonstration, we should be sorting the bars by the counts. Hopefully this answered your question!